# How to use an ideal diode in the virtuoso candence

Tags: cadence, cadence-virtuoso

I use the ideal diode  in the  virtuoso candence,but the log file show me an error when i simulate the circuit.

```
**error** (input.ckt:44) definition of model mydiode not found.Please specify a defined model name.
```

Here is my diode information,i don't know what is a "defined model name".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Cadence doesn't have an ideal model for a diode. You will need to use a diode from a PDK or create your own model file for a diode.